# Matplotlib point annotation, no scaling

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'd like to annotate a plot in matplotlib with filled and non-filled dots. I can create a circle patch, but the circle scales with my axes which is not my desired effect.

I can achieve this with

```
plt.plot(x,y,'.',markersize=10)
plt.plot(x,y,'o',markersize=10)
```

but both markers are filled even if I set `markerfacecolor=None`.

Comment: Did setting to 'none' work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sources it looks like you need to set markerfacecolor to 'none' and None.

Can you try this?

Ref : http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/errorbarseriesproperties.html

Comment: Thank you! It is indeed 'none' as opposed to None. Here is what I ended up using:
plt.plot(0,0,'o',markersize=10,markerfacecolor='none',markeredgewidth=1,markeredgecolor='black')